# Do LWR Digital Experiences support the audience mechanism?

Tags: community, digital-experience, lwr, audience, page-variation

[Audiences](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/communities_personalize_audiences/audiences_user_object) allow Aura Digital Experiences to present alternate content - page variations - based on location or record or user or permission attributes.

The [LWR Template Limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/template_limitations.htm) do not say that LWR Digital Experiences do not support Audiences but I do not see them in the LWR builder whereas I do in the Aura builder.

So does LWR support the Audience mechanism?

LWR builder:

[image: LWR screen shot]

Aura builder:

[image: Aura screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Summer Release, you can create Component Visibility Rules in LWR - see [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_component_visibility.htm&release=244&type=5)

> Make your enhanced LWR sites as dynamic as your users. With Expression Based Visibility, now generally available, you can show or hide individual components based on rules that contain a set of conditions. From the new Visibility tab on the component property panel, build rules and apply them based on User object and Profile fields. Create conditions that apply to a single component and access fields on the User and Product objects to show your components at the right time to the right users.

This is equivalent to Audiences on Components on a page and is based on attributes of the User (e.g., Guest or Authenticated, User->Contact->Account fields).  There is now a 'Visibility' attribute of the component where you define and assign the visibility criteria.  Also, each component can be defined to show/hide for mobile/tablet/desktop .

There is also a free Salesforce Labs App called 'Personalize Anything for Experience Cloud (LWR) that allows you to define criteria for a page section. See https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N4V00000HKXqnUAH